# progress bar only displays and does not update new to android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am trying to produce a progress bar to tell me the percentage of the file that I have downloaded so far. The progress bar is displaying, but it does not ever update, it stays static.

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                    values.add(line);             

                }
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(ourContext);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setMessage("File downloading...");
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                dialog.setProgress(0);
                dialog.setMax(values.size());
                dialog.show();

                progressBarStatus = 0;

                fileSize = 0;

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while(progressBarStatus < values.size()){
                            for(int i = 0; i < values.size();i++){
                                String[] data = values.get(i).split(",");
                                //Log.d("Test drive " ,data[1] );   

                                String[] dateSplit = data[1].split("[-]");
                                String month = dateSplit[1];
                                String day = dateSplit[0];
                                String year = dateSplit[2];

                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                try {
                                    cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").parse(month));
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    String error = e.toString();
                                    Dialog d = new Dialog(ourContext);
                                    d.setTitle("Error");
                                    TextView tv = new TextView(ourContext);
                                    tv.setText(error);
                                    d.setContentView(tv);
                                    d.show();
                                }

                                int monthInt = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
                                int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(year);
                                int dayInt = Integer.parseInt(day);                             

                                try {
                                    cashPotEntry(dayInt, monthInt, yearInt, data[3], data[2], data[4]);
                                    progressBarStatus++;
                                    Log.d("progress bar" ,progressBarStatus + " "  );                                   
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    String error = e.toString();
                                    Dialog d = new Dialog(ourContext);
                                    d.setTitle("Error");
                                    TextView tv = new TextView(ourContext);
                                    tv.setText(error);
                                    d.setContentView(tv);
                                    d.show();
                                }
                                }
                            progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    dialog.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if(progressBarStatus >= values.size()){
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                String error = e.toString();
                                Dialog d = new Dialog(ourContext);
                                d.setTitle("Error");
                                TextView tv = new TextView(ourContext);
                                tv.setText(error);
                                d.setContentView(tv);
                                d.show();
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();

        }
```

Comment: What is `progressBarHandler`? And why are you posting that? I don't think that makes any sense. Why not just simply call `setProgress()`?

Comment: as i said new to android was following a tutorial if u can show me a better way to use it i would be grateful

Comment: @LeventeKurusa : because you cannot call setProgress from just any thread

Comment: @OrettStanley : why do you have 2 loops ? my understanding is that progressBarValue is incremented at each iteration of the for loop, which would mean that exiting the for loop also exits the while loop. Why is your post not in the for loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove you `while` loop.

Put the `progressBarHandler.post` code in the `for` loop.

The way it is now, you never update the progress bar until you exit the `for` loop, and then, you exit the `while` loop as well.